# Does lying in a bed and not sleeping the whole night reset one's spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When one sleeps and skips night they reset their spawn.
Does lying in a bed but not skipping the night reset their spawn?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. There is no need to actually stay in the bed. All that matters is that you actually were laying down. So rightclicking on a bed and getting the message "you can only sleep at night" does not set your spawn. Getting in the bed, and immediately back out sets your spawn.